# $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\sin n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: limits

One of my teachers have given a limit to compute:

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|\sin n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

I have proved that if the limit exits it has to be $1$. (By using the fact that $\{n\pi\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$)

But I seem to have no idea how to approach the problem from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By using the fact that{$n \pi$} is dense. where it is dense?

Comment: I have used the fact that $\{n\pi\}$ can be made as close to $1$ as desired.

Comment: @Grobber I'd use the fact that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ $0<|\sin{n}|<1$, and since the argument will make the logarithm negatively *finite*, it will always be $o(n)$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: An approach: is there a subsequence of $\{n\pi\}$ that approaches $0$ so quickly that $(\{n\pi\})^n\to L<1$?

Comment: Dirty Rough answer: $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}|\sin n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \\= x^{\frac1{\infty}} ,\quad x\in [0,1]\\= x^0 = 1$$

Notice how the value of $x$ just oscillates in the interval :D

Comment: @Nick a sequence of numbers $x_n$ that converges to $0$ quickly enough can have $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^{1/n} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use this result: $$m>1,m<n,|n-m\pi|<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

then have $$|n-m\pi|>\dfrac{1}{m^{41}}$$
this reslut proof can see K.Mahler.on the approximation of $\pi$,Indag.Math.

so
$$1>|\sin{n}|=|\sin{(n-m\pi)}|>\dfrac{2}{\pi}|n-m\pi|>\dfrac{2}{\pi\cdot n^{41}}$$

Comment: That's a pretty crazy exponent of $41$. How hard is the result to prove? This is a question posed by a teacher, maybe there is an easier way to get a worse bound that still works to evaluate the limit? Or maybe the teacher didn't realize how hard the question was?

Comment: If $m$ and $n$ are both positive integers and $m>n$, then $m-n \geq 1$, which means $\pi m - n \geq 1 + (\pi-1)m > \pi$, then how can be $|n-m\pi| < \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @LiuGang,sorry,it's $m<n$

Comment: @math110 ok, so essentially you said the speed that a subsequence of $n$ approaches integer times $\pi$ can't be faster than polynomial

Comment: @math110 I think is $42$ not $41$.

Comment: @math110 Please edit your answer, is $42$!

Comment: @math110 Could you please give more information regarding the article you mention? For instance, a link, or some more explicit reference.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/mahler/docs/119.pdf