# Finding limit of $a_n = \frac{1}{n|\sin n|}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n|\sin n|}$. Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ if it exists. It's known that $b_n = \frac{1}{n\sin n}$ is divergent but what about $a_n = \frac{1}{n|\sin n|}$? I tried to show that $a_n$ converges to $0$ using definition but I am stuck on $\frac{1}{|\sin n|} \lt \epsilon$. Also attempting to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges with different tests, like comparison test , was unsuccessful.

Comment: If you know that $\frac{1}{n\sin n}$ diverges, you're done.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: Assuming that $b_n$ is divergent, how could $a_n$ converge?

Comment: @IvanNeretin For example $(-1)^n$ diverges but $|(-1)^n|$ converges.

Comment: Good. Now you have to rule out this possibility.

Comment: BTW, how do you know that $b_n$ diverges? The proof of that fact could be quite handy to you now.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Because $\frac{1}{n\sin n} \le \frac{1}{n|\sin n|}$ and $\frac{1}{n\sin n}$ diverges, then $\frac{1}{n|\sin n|}$ also diverges. Is that right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You didn't rule out the possibility that the series behaves akin to $(-1)^n$. (It doesn't, but you still have to prove that.)

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't know how to rule out that possibility. Could you help please?

Comment: Do you know about convergents in continued fractions? I'm afraid we can't move on without that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin No, I don't know about that.

Comment: Then again, _how_ do you know that $b_n$ diverges?

Comment: @IvanNeretin This is the proof that I know: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-show-that-the-sequence-1-n-sin-n-diverges

Comment: Well, this proof applies to your case just fine, word for word. The complicated stuff I mentioned is swept under the rug they call _"theorem on approximation of real numbers"_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So how can I find a proof for divergence of $a_n$? What should I read before that? This question occurred to me when tried to solve this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906132/displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-sin-n-frac1n What do you think about it?

Comment: You already have the proof. If you want to know how they arrived at the theorem of approximations, go read about the **continued fractions**. As for the other question you mentioned now, it is a great deal harder.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Okay, thanks a lot for your responses.

Comment: Obviously $\displaystyle\color{red}{\tt ZERO}$ because $\displaystyle\sin\left(n\right)$ never vanishes out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will use the fact $\pi$ is an irrational number.

By [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz's_theorem_%28number_theory%29), there are infinite many integer pairs $n,m$ such that

$$\left| \pi - \frac{n}{m} \right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m^2}$$
It is easy to see the theorem remains valid when we restrict $n, m$ to positive integers.

For such a pair of $n, m$, we have

$$\left|m \pi - n \right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5} m}
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}n}\left(\pi + \left|\frac{n}{m} - \pi\right|\right) < \frac{\pi + 1}{\sqrt{5} n}$$

This leads to

$$|\sin(n)| = |\sin(m\pi - n)| \le |m\pi - n| < \frac{\pi + 1}{\sqrt{5}n}
\implies \frac{1}{n|\sin(n)|} > \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\pi + 1 }$$
Since there are infinitely many such $n$, we can deduce

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n|\sin(n)|} \ge \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\pi + 1 }$$

On the other direction, since $\pi$ is irrational, $n$ will be [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) modulo $\pi$. This implies there are infinitely many $n$ such that $|\sin(n)| > \frac12$. For such $n$, we have

$$\frac{1}{n|\sin(n)|} < \frac{2}{n}$$
Since there are infinitely many such $n$, we have

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n|\sin(n)|} \le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n} = 0$$

Since the [limsup and liminf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) of the sequence $\frac{1}{n|\sin(n)|}$ is different, the limit $\displaystyle\;\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n|\sin(n)|}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I am sorry, I have just finished composing an answer almost identical to yours, I did not notice your reply. I hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 3):

The limit does not exist in either case. Let us consider the continued fraction of $\pi$,
$$ \pi = [3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, \ldots]$$
which is infinite since $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ be its $n$-th convergent. By the properties of continued fractions
$$ \left|q_n \pi - p_n\right|\leq \frac{1}{q_n} $$
and by Lagrange's theorem
$$ \left|\sin(p_n)-\sin(\pi q_n)\right| \leq |p_n-\pi q_n|\leq \frac{1}{q_n}, $$
so 
$$ p_n |\sin(p_n)|\leq \frac{p_n}{q_n} $$
and the RHS is $\leq \pi$ if we assume that $n$ has the suitable parity. This implies
$$ \limsup_{m\to +\infty} \frac{1}{m|\sin m|}\geq \frac{1}{\pi}. $$
On the other hand $m|\sin m|$ can be pretty large, too. Let us assume that $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}$ is a convergent of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $Q_n$ is odd.
$$ \left|\sin(P_n)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}Q_n\right)\right|\leq \frac{1}{Q_n} $$
implies that $|\sin(Q_n)|\geq 1-\frac{1}{Q_n}$, hence $Q_n|\sin(Q_n)|\geq Q_n-1$ and 
$$ \liminf_{m\to +\infty}\frac{1}{m|\sin m|}=0$$
contradicts the existence of the limit. The last line can be proved through probabilistic arguments, too: if we consider a "random integer" $M$, the probability that $|\sin M|\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is $\geq\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon$, hence $m|\sin m|$ can be as large as $\frac{m}{3}$ infinitely often.

Comment: +1 a nice answer as usual.